# How to remove activity title in android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I'm trying to remove the title (in red in the picture) from my activity with no luck.

Until now I have tried:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And this

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<!-- Hides the Action Bar -->
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

The image is next

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpMfE.png

Also I want to know the name of that title bar

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yes, this gives me "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

in your activity, if you are using `ActionBarCompat` support file,

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

I hope this will help you.